# no desktop: signon-ui segfault in libqxcb.so

Tags: 14.04, updates

Ubuntu 14.04 LTS all updates installed
After the last update my PC does not start the desktop anymore.
PC is set up for autologin.

SSHing in from another PC, the logfile says:

```
signon-ui segfault in libqxcb.so
```

The last update were a number of QT packages according to the `history.log`:

```
Start-Date: 2016-07-01  07:50:04
Commandline: aptdaemon role='role-commit-packages' sender=':1.115'
Upgrade: oxideqt-codecs-extra:amd64 (1.15.7-0ubuntu0.14.04.1, 1.15.8-0ubuntu0.14.04.1), 
liboxideqtcore0:amd64 (1.15.7-0ubuntu0.14.04.1, 1.15.8-0ubuntu0.14.04.1), 
liboxideqtquick0:amd64 (1.15.7-0ubuntu0.14.04.1, 1.15.8-0ubuntu0.14.04.1), 
liboxideqt-qmlplugin:amd64 (1.15.7-0ubuntu0.14.04.1, 1.15.8-0ubuntu0.14.04.1)
End-Date: 2016-07-01  07:50:09
```

So I rolled these back with: `sudo dpkg i 'packagename'`
since the previous versions were still in the cache.

Alas no luck, still no desktop. Searching the interwebs high and low I have not come up with a cause and fix. 
Anybody got a clue?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I took the sledgehammer approach and upgraded to 16.04 LTS.
Everything runs as expected.
Bummer I couldn't find out what the cause was.